# how to update nested attributes through controller from simple form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm trying to update a nested association that has 2 parents, both one to many

company has many company_users and users have many company_users also.

company_users both belong to company and users

this is my current form

```
<%= simple_form_for([:admin, @company_user], url: @company_user.new_record? ? admin_company_users_path : admin_company_user_path) do |f| %>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4 columns">   
       <%= render partial: "admin/layouts/form_errors", locals: {instance: @company_user} %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for(@company) do |p| %>
      <%= p.input :name %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for(@user) do |s| %>
      <%= s.input :full_name %>
    <% end %>
      <%= f.input :role %>       
     <%= f.submit class: "submit" %>
  </div>
</div>
 <% end %>
```

the fields are correctly displaying the full name and name, but when i hit the update button, nothing happens

here is my controller

```
module Admin
class CompanyUsersController < BaseController


before_action :load_company_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
respond_to :html


def index
  @company_users = CompanyUser.includes(:user, :company).page(params[:page])
end


def edit
end

def update
  flash[:notice] = 'Company User was successfully updated.' if @company_user.update(permitted_params)
  respond_with @company_user, location: admin_company_users_url
end

def destroy
  @company_user.destroy
  respond_with @company_user, location: admin_company_users_url
end


def load_company_user
  @company_user = CompanyUser.find(params[:id])
  @company = @company_user.company
  @user = @company_user.user
end

def permitted_params
  params.require(:company_user).permit(:role, pets_attributes: [:full_name,:name])
end
end
end
```

i've tried calling the permitted method on both the company and user instance objects, but they complain about not knowing the role param

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `permitted_params` method. It should be like below.

```
def permitted_params
  params.require(:company_user).permit(:role, company_attributes: [:name], user_attributes: [:full_name])
end
```